# i18n.changeLanguage send part of string to locize, not nn-NO, but only nn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I'm using locize.io and i18n for translation of my application. Everything was working just fine, but since I added new language with dash: "nn-NO", I'm getting empty {}.

I'm changing language like this: i18n.changeLanguage("nn-NO"), but method sends to server not full string somehow:

Request URL:https://api.locize.io/KEY_HERE/latest/nn
Request Method:GET

And when I manually tried with console and cUrl update this request with "nn-NO", I got all translated sentances for "nn-NO" language.

It looks like changeLanguage method doesn't support "-" and cut this string, taking to account only first part of it.

Maybe somebody had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you gonna have same problem just change your i18n configuration:

```
load: 'languageOnly'
```

To this:

```
load: 'all'
```

So, configuration gonna look like this:

```
i18n

    .use(Backend)
    .use(LastUsed)
    .use(Editor)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: false,
        saveMissing: true,
        whitelist: [list of allowed languages],
        ns: [list of namespaces],
        defaultNS: your_default_namespace,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
        backend: locizeOptions,
        locizeLastUsed: locizeOptions,
        editor: {
            ...locizeOptions,
            onEditorSaved: async (lng, ns) => {
                await i18n.reloadResources(lng, ns);
                i18n.emit('editorSaved');
            },
        },
        react: {
            bindI18n: 'languageChanged editorSaved',
            useSuspense: false
        },
        load: 'all'
    });
```

I found an answer in documentation:

"language codes to lookup, given set language is 'en-US': 'all' --> ['en-US', 'en', 'dev'], 'currentOnly' --> 'en-US', 'languageOnly' --> 'en' "

https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options